# CXFRS webservice don't work

Tags: web-services, maven, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, cxfrs

Fuse esb.
component: CXFRs
webservice

I have some problem with my webservice.

This is the POM.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
             </dependency>
                <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
          <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
          </dependency>

          <!-- logging -->
          <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing & Camel Plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CXF -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
      <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0.redhat-610379</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0.redhat-610379</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.0.redhat-610379</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0.redhat-610379</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.0.redhat-610379</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m10</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>
```

This the route:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0         

       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint             

    http://camel.apache.org/schema/     
     blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

  <bean id="helloBean" class="com.mycompany.camel.blueprint.HelloBean">
      <property name="say" value="Hi from Camel"/>
  </bean>
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:9090/route"
              serviceClass="com.mycompany.camel.blueprint.Testws"/>
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route>
    <from uri="cxfrs:beanId:rsServer"/>
    <log message="test"/>
    <marshal>
      <json library="Jackson"/>
    </marshal>
  </route>
</camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

This is the function:

```
     package com.mycompany.camel.blueprint;

     import javax.ws.rs.GET;
     import javax.ws.rs.Path;
      import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
     import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
     import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


   @Path("/")
    public class Testws {

    @GET
    @Path("/test/{id}/{id2}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getAssets(@PathParam("id") String id, 
        @PathParam("id2")        String id2){
        return null;
    }

    }
```

And this is the error message:

```
 Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
at                         org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.*
 AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources
(AbstractJAXRSFactor     yBean.java:322)
at  2)
... 55 more
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException - Reason for the error is, CXF cannot find the matching resource for the given request.

To comply with best practice, donot use fully qualified url in the "address attribute". Below are the working sample, please try the same in your code. It will work

**Camel DSL:**

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="/"
                      serviceClass="com.guru.service.ControlService"
                      loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20">           
           <cxf:providers>
                <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider"/>                   
           </cxf:providers>
   </cxf:rsServer>

<route id="esbRoute">
    <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsServerr"/>
    <to uri="mock:test" />
</route>
```

**Java code**

```
@Path("/controlcservice")
public class ControlService {

    @POST
    @Path("/save")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
    public ResponseDetail save(ControlEntity entity) {
                System.out.println("Hi Im inside rest api");
        return null ;

    }
  }
```

And the path to access this rest resource will be "http://localhost:xxxx/controlcservice/save"